# How similar are jBPM 5 and 6?

Tags: drools, jbpm

I'm starting some jBPM development over the summer, but apparently the version 6 book isn't out yet. Is the version 5 book close enough to get me started? I haven't found the online tutorials to be all that informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level...

- The DRL used for writing rules is more or less the same.
- The Java API used for interacting with Drools has similar concepts
  (such as sessions and firing rules), however the classes changed
  names, and the means of loading rules into the knowledge base is
  quite different, so your Java code will need to be updated.
- The workbench (which you may or may not intend to use) has mostly
  quite similar screens for editing rules. There is a migration tool,
  which *should* make it relatively easy to upgrade.

I would expect that you are likely (at least initially) to be learning your way around the rules syntax and the (seemingly) weird behaviour of rules engines compared to more familiar procedural or functional code. As such, I don't think you are likely to lose too much by getting started with 5.5 and upgrading as and when it feels like a good idea.